# Bulk insert file to SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

Can you use a CSV with file locations of multiple files that are to be inserted in the SQL table?

The type would be varbinary(max) and the files are Excel files.

I haven't been able to find any definitive answers on that.

Comment: Are you after [Datatype to save excel file in sql server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492469/datatype-to-save-excel-file-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that use SSIS in order to convert your excel file in SQL Server. You can also use convert for each file in specific location with SSIS Component.

Comment: So I am not trying to import the contents of the Excel files but the whole files. Each file into a varbinary column.

Comment: @sd+dracula. I just suggest that use SSIS. I don't know any other way to do this.